# Tag synonym request: [winxp] -> [windows-xp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[winxp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/winxp) was created yesterday. We already have [windows-xp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp), which is used extensively. But "winxp" is a pretty common abbreviation for "Windows XP." Therefore, I recommend making [winxp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/winxp) a synonym of [windows-xp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp).

Comment: Next time you can also suggest the tag before opening a meta post (you have the rep). It will allow you to expose it, allow others to vote in it (6 votes and its approved) and if a moderator is around it will be just a click away to approve it automatically ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, [winxp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/winxp) was synn'ed to [windows-xp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp).